# Echo the filename of the image

Tags: php, curl

It seems the simple `echo $image` doesn't do the trick for this one:

```
<?php
include_once 'class.get.image.php';

// initialize the class
$image = new GetImage;

// just an image URL
$image->source = $_POST["url"];
$image->save_to = 'images/'; // with trailing slash at the end
$get = $image->download('curl'); // using GD

if($get)
{
    echo 'The image has been saved.';
    echo $image;
}
?>
```

Here's [class.get.image.php](http://pastebin.com/VaAnezgA) You see i've inserted `echo $image;` hoping it would **display at least the filename of the image** but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo basename($image->source);
```

that will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`$image` is an object, and if you wish to echo an object, the class must define the `__toString` method.

In your class, it looks like the filename is stored in `$this->source`. Therefore you might want to consider adding a `__toString` method to your class that is similar to the following:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->source;
}
```

After you add this, you will be able to do `echo $image`, and it will echo whatever `__toString` returns.